# New iOS Bundle ID Not Showing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, app-id

I made a new App ID earlier today for an app I'm working on.  I've done over 30 apps, and never had issues with this.  However, when I went to select the Bundle ID when setting up the app in iTunes Connect, the new ID I made will not show up.  Is something wrong on my end, or on Apple's end?

Comment: Same happens to me, apparenlty we have to wait.

Comment: does waiting solves the issue? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching and searching, and never found answers. In end up I had to wait, i didn't like it but I did. But it did end up coming onto iTunes connect.

My Wait Time was 6 hours.

So anyone who is in same situation as me. Just be confident in what you did and wait.

Note for next time. Allow potential wait time for this. I am a day behind schedule now.